# communicate with remote host using camel-netty tcp

Tags: tcp, apache-camel, netty

I have a program running on a remote host that I need to connect to, handshake, then listen for messages. I have setup the following camel route:

```
<route>
   <from uri="netty:tcp://localhost:50001?decoders=#decoders&amp;sync=false" />
   <bean ref="TransformMessage" method="inboundDecoder" />
   <to uri="eventadmin:messages/aacus/inbound" />
</route>

<route>
   <from uri="eventadmin:messages/aacus/outbound" />
   <bean ref="TransformMessage" method="outboundEncoder" />
   <to uri="netty:tcp://192.168.0.111:50001?allowDefaultCodec=false&amp;sync=false" />
</route>
```

My question is how do I make this work? If I establish the route using

`<from uri="netty:tcp://192.168.0.111:50001?decoders=#decoders&amp;sync=false" />`

it fails with a binding error.

How can I setup the connection to respond on a specific port without modifying the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with either camel-mina nor camel-netty at this time of writing. A consumer can only bind to a local server. There is a JIRA ticket at Apache to implement such a new feature for the future. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-1077

Comment: Thanks Claus, I was afraid this was the case. Rather frustrating that this isn't supported as it seems like a common and obvious use-case. I have worked around this issue by implementing a custom component for Camel that handles my TCP communication.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following workaround:

Instead ob `192.168.0.111` use `localhost`.
Then install "socat" and start it as follows

```
socat -s -u tcp4:192.168.0.111:50001 tcp4:localhost:50001
```

This will Tunnel your remote connection to the local service you created with camel/netty.